# Git pull and git push are not responsive anymore after updating macos to mojave

Tags: git, macos, macos-mojave

Git pull, git push and git clone are not returning anything at all since after updating my macos to mojave. however git status is working fine

I have tried reinstalling git with brew which what i am using, that didnt work. Also tried with built in git and that didnt work either.

Although occasionally after I restart my machine git pull will only work once and then the same issue again (and yes I have tried a couple of different wifi's before you saying my internet speed is slow)

and I have ran xcode-select --install which returning nothing to install as its already installed.

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated

Comment: Homebrew uses Git under the hood. Is Homebrew working fine on your machine?

Comment: yes it is @jubobs